# How can I convert Rep[Option[Instant]] to Rep[Option[String]] in scala

Tags: scala, slick

I am working with scala play 2, slick and postgresql as database. One of my function is like

```
def getAllCustomersWithAccount: Future[Seq[CustomerDetail]] = {
val joinException = for {
  (customer, account) <- table join accountTable on (_.id === _.id)
} yield (customer.id, account.name, account.phone, account.email, customer.status, customer.balance, customer.payable, customer.created, customer.updated)

val result = db.run(joinException.result)
result.map(row => row.map(x => CustomerDetail(x._1, x._2, x._3, x._4, x._5, x._6, x._7, x._8, x._9)))
}
```

This code is not working. The problem is created and updated property of customer. That is customer.created and customer.updated is Rep[Option[Instant]] which is date time. If i escape those two column (customer.created and customer.updated) then it's ok. That is

```
def getAllCustomersWithAccount: Future[Seq[CustomerDetail]] = {
    val joinException = for {
      (customer, account) <- table join accountTable on (_.id === _.id)
    } yield (customer.id, account.name, account.phone, account.email, customer.status, customer.balance, customer.payable)
    val result = db.run(joinException.result)
    result.map(row => row.map(x => CustomerDetail(x._1, x._2, x._3, x._4, x._5, x._6, x._7)))
}
```

This code is working fine. I want to convert Rep[Option[Instant]] to Rep[Option[String]]. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Slick requires `Mapping` from `custom types` to known `jdbc types`. Provide an implicit mapping for slick from `DateTime` to `Timestamp` or `Instant` to `Timestamp` in your case. This helps `slick`to understand `custom types` in terms of `native database supported types`.

```
implicit def jodaTimeMapping: BaseColumnType[DateTime] = MappedColumnType.base[DateTime, Timestamp](
dateTime => new Timestamp(dateTime.getMillis),
timeStamp => new DateTime(timeStamp.getTime))
```

above `implicit` helps `Slick` to convert `DateTime` to `Timestamp` and vice versa.

**In case of Instant type**

assuming `Instant` is a wrapper around `DateTime`

```
case class Instant(time: DateTime)

implicit def instantMapping: BaseColumnType[Instant] = MappedColumnType.base[Instant, Timestamp](
instant => new Timestamp(instant.time.getMillis),
timeStamp => Instant(new DateTime(timeStamp.getTime)))
```

**Slick Implicit mapping for java.time.Instant**

```
import java.sql.Timestamp

implicit def instantMapping: BaseColumnType[Instant] = MappedColumnType.base[Instant, Timestamp](
instant => new Timestamp(instant.toEpochMilli),
timeStamp => Instant.ofEpochMilli(timeStamp.getTime))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please clear your answer. How can I fix the problem? I want to just convert `Rep[Option[Instant]]` to `Rep[Option[String]]`

Comment: Provide conversion from `Instant` to `String` . implicit def instantMapping: BaseColumnType[Instant] = MappedColumnType.base[Instant, String](....)

Comment: Need more info about instant ...to write complete code

Comment: @Md.ShougatHossain what is `Instant` ? is it a custom object ? if its a custom object. what are its contents

Comment: java.time.Instant

Comment: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type slick.driver.PostgresDriver.BaseColumnType[com.sun.jmx.snmp.Timestamp]

Comment: @Md.ShougatHossain ... here the `Timestamp` is `java.sql.Timestamp` .. wrong timestamp is imported in the code. Please check